# Showing that $n\log n - n$ is $\Omega(n)$

Tags: asymptotics

Prove that $n\log{n} − n$ is $\Omega(n)$.

I do know the answer:

$\log{n} ≥ 2, \forall n \ge 4$.

Thus, $n\log{n}−n\ge n ,\forall n\ge 4 \implies n \log n − n ∈ Ω(n)$.

But can someone please explain how  its done. where did $2$, $\forall n$ and $4$ came from.
Then how was $n, \forall n \ge 4$ added.

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of $\Omega$?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Your question is a very basic one. Let me direct you towards our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599) which cover some fundamentals you seem to be missing in detail. Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific problems you encountered. Good luck!

Comment: It seems your issue may be with reading mathematics, not Landau notation.

Answer (score 3):

According to the definition of big Omega, in order to show that $n\log n - n = \Omega(n)$, we need to come up with $n_0$ and $c$ such that all $n \geq n_0$ satisfy $n\log n - n \ge cn$.

Let us assume that the logarithm is to base 2. When $n \geq 4$, we have $\log n \geq \log 4 = 2$, and so $n\log n - n \geq 2n - n = n$. Therefore we can take $n_0 = 4$ and $c = 1$ and satisfy the requirements for $n\log n - n = \Omega(n)$.

The choice of $4$ is arbitrary — any $n_0 > 2$ would work (for an appropriate value of $c$).